# Unknown Gap on Top of Page / Flash Full-Screen Issues

Tags: flash, samsung-smart-tv

I am developing a Samsung Smart TV app using flash. The app is embedded within the html page:

```
<body style="margin:0;border:0;padding:0" onload="Main.onLoad();" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">
<div style="margin-top:0;border:0;padding:0;background-color:red">
asdf
</div>
<!-- Flash -->
<div>
    <object style="margin-top:0;border:0;padding:0" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flashobj" width="960" height="540">
        <param name="movie" value="./Server.swf">
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    </object>


</div>              
</body>
```

as you can see margin, padding and border are all set to 0. the TV application dimensions are set to 960x540.  and so is the flash object, but for some reason there is a white gap above the flash object.  I put a div there to test what is creating the gap, but this div is the first element within <body> and is below the gap.  I tried changing the color of the body, the white bar changes color as well.

Also the flash object is pushed down out of the view dimensions.

What could be creating this gap and how can i remove it?
or is there a certain way to make the flash application fullscreen on the smart tv?

[image: unknown white space]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird.. First time I see this kind of problem.

You can always use `position:absolute` and it should be enough to solve the problem.

```
<object style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:960px; height:540px" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flashobj" width="960" height="540">
    <param name="movie" value="./Server.swf">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
</object>
```